Запомнить список файлов через диалоговое окно
Здравствуйте Уважаемые программисты!
Подскажите пожалуйста пример кода excel-vba, как можно через вызванное диалоговое окно (пример на рисунке ниже) через кнопки сверху окна "Выбрать файлы" или "Открыть папку с файлами" дать пользователю возможность таким образом указать список файлов. Эти файлы появляются в центре окна, например, в Listbox.  Далее по кнопке "Старт" запустить некую процедуру, которая работает с этим списком.

Заранее спасибо!

Для выбора файлов списком используйте:
Sub SelectFiles()
  Dim a, s
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Show
    Set a = .SelectedItems
  End With
  ' далее в качестве примера имена выбранных файлов распечатываются в отладочном окне
  For Each s In a
    Debug.Print s
  Next
End Sub

Для выбора папки используйте:
Sub SelectFolder()
  Dim a
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    Set a = .SelectedItems
  End With
  Debug.Print a(1)
End Sub

